# Frobenius Inner Product between two matrices in Eigen3

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Is there a simple and quick solution to calculate the Frobenius Inner Product between two 3x3 matrices in Eigen3?

Comment: Can you specify the mathematical properties of the matrix-dotproduct? I have never heard of that before, only of dotproduct of vectors. Maybe give example input values and the desired output.

Comment: By dot product of matrices A and B do you mean trace(A^t B)? Or maybe the Hadamard product?

Comment: Can you show an example with a 2x2 matrix,

Comment: With dot product I mean the sum of the Hadamard produrct or the Frobenius inner product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for the [inner product of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product), a possible (maybe not optimal) solution may be

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Eigen/Dense"
     
    int main()
    {
      
    Eigen::Matrix3d A, B;
    A << 1, 2, 3,
            4,5,6,
            7,8,9;
    B << 10, 11, 12,
             13,14,15,
             16,17,18;

    Eigen::Matrix3d C;
    C = A.transpose()*B;
    
    std::cout << C.trace() << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but this might be useful.

You can map your matrices into vectors and compute the inner product between said vectors (it also works if you are dealing with complex valued matrices).

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> vec_A(A.data(), A.cols()*A.rows());
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> vec_B(B.data(), B.cols()*B.rows());
const double frob_inner = vec_A.dot(vec_B);
```

Maps allows you te reinterpret your matrices as vectors without copy, it is equivalent to the [Vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), which can be used to define the Frobenius inner product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a normal matrix multiplication

```
Eigen::Matrix3d a;
Eigen::Matrix3d b;

Eigen::Matrix3d product = a * b;
```

Comment: No that ist es not :D perhaps I have found the solution: 
c = (A.cwiseProduct(B)).sum() where c is a scalar and A, B are Matrices

Comment: So you mean the dot product between the column vectors?

Comment: I mean the Frobenius inner product.
In Python:
c = np.sum(A * B) whereas * is not the matrix multiplcation, it is the component-wise multiplication

Comment: @MichaelSchw You should better clarify this by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66813402/edit) your question, not in the comments of an answer.